# How to install kernel for jupyter notebook in virtual environment located in D drive?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, virtualenv

I want to install kernel for jupyter notebook in virtual environment instead of local C drive so that I can download modules and packages in my virtual environment and use them from the virtual environment where my new kernel will be located.

When I try to install kernel with the command in my virtual environment located in D drive:
(jupenv) PS D:\AI APPS> py -m ipykernel install --user --name=jupenv

It gets installed in location:
C:\Users\rick\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\jupenv

But I need to install kernel in D:\AI APPS\jupenv so that I can install the modules and packages used for jupyter notebook in 'jupenv' where I can use packages independently .

Due to this problem now I have to install modules outside the virtual environment 'jupenv', and it is installed in location  c:\users\rick\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages  where the default ipykernel is located